How to install NVIDIA driver using Ubuntu recovery mode?
I met a problem while uninstalling the Nvidia CUDA. I used the command from the official manual.
They are:
Debian / Ubuntu
To remove CUDA Toolkit:
sudo apt-get --purge remove "cuda" "cublas" "cufft" "cufile" "curand" 
"cusolver" "cusparse" "gds-tools" "npp" "nvjpeg" "nsight*" "nvvm"
To clean up the uninstall:
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge -V
So now my laptop has nothing related to Nvidia at all, including the basic driver for graphic interface. When I boot into the Ubuntu system, the desktop is black. No pictures, no texts, even no terminal interface. I hope to reinstall the Nvidia driver (version is 560 if I remember correctly).
Could anyone tell me how to achieve this goal?
Many thanks in advance!

Ok, with the help of ChatGPT, I managed to reinstall the Nvidia driver. Version 560 can not be installed due to some unmet dependency issues. Version 535 was installed and solved the problem.
So what I did are:

Boot into recovery mode and enter "root - Drop to root shell prompt";
Remount file system with permission to write: mount -o remount,rw /
Enable Networking: systemctl start NetworkManager
Update packages
sudo apt update sudo apt upgrade 
Add PPA for graphics drivers:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update

Install the driver: sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535

Then in the end reboot. Everything works like before.
I'm happy to be able to solve it in such a short time and hope this answer may help others if anyone has same problems as I do.
Cheers! :)
